# ‘magrittr’ 403 Forbiddened and unable to be installed

Tags: r, installation, package, http-status-code-403, magrittr

I am having a problem with downloading the `magrittr` package from CRAN. Initially it seem like my company is blocking me from downloading the zip file. I jump through hoops and obtained a high level internet access, also tried a few simple fixes, but the issue persists. I am able to download other packages from CRAN, but `magrittr` just seem to be deemed unsafe and getting 403ed no matter what I tried.

Also `magrittr` seem to be one of the core packages that is required by lots of package, so life is very hard without it.

```
> options(download.file.method = "wininet")

> install.packages("magrittr")
Warning in install.packages :
  the 'wininet' method is deprecated for http:// and https:// URLs
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/magrittr_2.0.3.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/magrittr_2.0.3.zip': HTTP status was '403 Forbidden'
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/magrittr_2.0.3.zip'
Warning in install.packages :
  download of package ‘magrittr’ failed
> devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘magrittr’
> install.packages("cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/magrittr/…", repos = NULL, type="source")
Warning: invalid package 'cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/magrittr/…'
Error: ERROR: no packages specified
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/magrittr/…’ had non-zero exit status
```

```
[1] "R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16 ucrt)"
```

I have unticked the "Use secure method for https download" option in Options.

I have set my download method with `options(download.file.method = "wininet")`

I have tried changing Global repository to other ones.

I also tried to installing an archived version.

From cybersecurity side they can see that the `magrittr` zip URL is blocked by Zscaler. But other package's zip URL is not blocked.

```
install.packages("installr")
Warning in install.packages :
  the 'wininet' method is deprecated for http:// and https:// URLs
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.3/installr_0.23.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 348583 bytes (340 KB)
downloaded 340 KB

package ‘installr’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

Comment: "the 'wininet' method is deprecated for http:// and https:// URLs" <- use something else?

Comment: Hi Mark, tried all of the methods and all of them came back with fail.

Comment: Have you tried entering the URL to the zip file in a browser to see if it downloads (it does for me) ? If the issue is a company IT policy there isn't much we can do to help.

Comment: Hi Neil, talked to cybersecurity, 'magrittr' is blocked. However R is a tech use approved environment so I am now trying to request them to whitelist the link.

Comment: @JimmyX_NZ if that fails, you can use the native pipe instead - I just started using it, it's great! Basically identical to the magrittr pipe

Comment: Right, I will look into native pipe tonight.